# How to compile raw source code of SQLite3 in ubuntu?

Tags: sqlite

I want to modify the sqlite3 source code and compile.
I can download and compile the sqlite-autoconf-source file(this one is amalgamation version) but I want to modify the seperated source code and compile it. How should i do?

I DO NOT want to modify the amalgamation version of source code and compile.

Help me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's really important read README.md
It works good Try this
first, change the permission the configure file
(e.g : chmod 700 configure)
and make the directory bld (It's recommended, but not required)

../sqlite-src-xxx/configure
make
make sqlite3.c

and complete!